# How to recursively list Google Drive files and folders up to level N in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to list all files and folders of google drive up to some level. The code below is listing all the files and their folders (until it exceeds its time limit) and logs them. How to I add some way to stop if it recursively went, let´s say, 3 levels of subfolders?

```
function listFolders(folder) {
  folder = folder || DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folderName = folder.getName();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var fileName = files.next().getName();
    Logger.log(folderName + " :: " + fileName);
  }
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    listFolders(subfolders.next());
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it might be helpful: https://alicekeeler.com/2020/05/05/google-drive-list-the-files/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modified script:

When you use this modified script, please run `main()`.

```
function main() { // Added
  const folder = // Please set here.
  const n = 3; // Please set here. This sample sets 3 as your question.
  listFolders(folder, n);
}

function listFolders(folder, n) { // Modified
  folder = folder || DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var folderName = folder.getName();
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var fileName = files.next().getName();
    Logger.log(folderName + " :: " + fileName);
  }

  if (--n == 0) return; // Added

  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    listFolders(subfolders.next(), n); // Modified
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Your script is Google Apps Script. So I modified your script as Google Apps Script.
- Please modify it for your situation.

If I misunderstood your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: your version is working fine. I had trying something similar before but I think I was redefining n, so it never stopped at the intended level. Thank you!

Comment: @Adriano_epifas I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.